# Importing Angular2 Components with Absolute URLs

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

Following is the directory structure of a example project:

```
app
|-components
| |-hero-detail
| | |-hero-detail.component.ts (HeroDetailComponent)
|-services
| |-hero.service.ts (HeroService)
```

I want to use `HeroService` in `HeroDetailComponent`.

Currently I am importing `HeroService` into `HeroDetailComponent` using the following statement:

```
import {HeroService} from '../../services/hero.service'
```

But I do not like having to refer to `HeroService` with a relative URL. Instead, I want it to be absolute like this:

```
import {HeroService} from 'app/services/hero.service'
```

How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
import {HeroService} from '/app/services/hero.service'
```

assuming that `app` is a root folder of your Web server.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how Angular packages are imported without the need for relative paths?  eg: `import {Component} from '@angular/core';`. You can do the same with your services!

If you're using a setup similar to the quickstart at the Angular site (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart), step 4 had you place the following in your `index.html`:

You can use this script to configure SystemJS and tell it where to find your services using non-relative paths.  Go to https://angular.io/guide/quickstart and select the SystemJS tab to see how the quickstart file is configured.  You can add to custom mappings to the `map` array. For instance, adding `'myservices': 'app/services'` would make the array look something like:

```
var map = {
    'app':      'app',
    '@angular':     'node_modules/@angular',
    'rxjs':         'node_modules/rxjs',
    'myservices':   'app/services'
};
```

Notice that the path in `map` isn't the path to the typescript files, but the path where the typescript compiler will place the JS files.  This setting should allow you then to import class `CustomService` that lives in `custom.service.ts` file with `Import {CustomService} from 'myservices/custom.service'`

If the imports fail, go back to SystemJS configuration and be sure that in the `packages` array, you have `app` registered and defaultExtension set to `js`.  The excerpt below was taken from the quickstart guide:

```
var packages = {
    'app':  { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
};
```